# Find outstanding requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, android-location

I want to know if there is a way to tell if anyone (not necessarily my application) has called requestLocationUpdates.  I am writing a service that monitors location, but I don't want to interfere with other apps (e.g. Waze, Endomondo) that might be monitoring location.
I don't see any API in the LocationManager object that can tell me if there is an outstanding request for location update.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think that your requests for locations will "interfere with other apps"?

Comment: Empirical observation: that is what happens when I run requestLocationUpdates (not in passive mode) from my service, and then try to run an application that uses GPS.

Comment: You might consider explaining, then, what you mean by "interfere with other apps".

Comment: Endomondo, for example, gets stuck "locating...", and can't get a GPS reading.

Comment: That sounds more like a bug in Endomondo. One app requesting location updates should not "interfere with other apps" also requesting location updates. If you can create a reproducible test case that demonstrates otherwise (and does not in turn depend upon the behavior of closed-source apps as evidence of behavior), post it somewhere, as I'd love to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for api >= 8, you can find out if an application has called `requestLocationUpdates` by calling

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, minTime, minDist, listener);
```

Official document

> public static final String PASSIVE_PROVIDER

Added in API level 8

> A special location provider for receiving locations without actually
>   initiating a location fix.
>
> This provider can be used to passively receive location updates when
>   other applications or services request them without actually
>   requesting the locations yourself. This provider will return locations
>   generated by other providers. You can query the getProvider() method
>   to determine the origin of the location update. Requires the
>   permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, although if the GPS is not enabled
>   this provider might only return coarse fixes.
>
> Constant Value: "passive"

onLocationChanged will not be called until some application request a fix.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know whether another GPS based application is running or not.  I want to use an active provider if there are no outstanding requests.  If another app. is generating requests, then I want to rely on getLastKnownLocation().

Comment: You can register for the passive provider as above and set up a countdown timer with a time you want. In the onFinish() of the countdown timer you start other provider say GPS. In the onLocationChanged you checked if the provider for the fix is the passive provider, if so you cancel the timer and start it again. This way if some other app is requesting location update then you do not request and if there is no request from other app after a certain amount of time you request location update in your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no means by which you can determine what other applications are doing with location updates, beyond indirectly via `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`.